# Reducing .jpeg PFFiles stored on Parse.com

Tags: parse-platform, jpeg, parse-cloud-code

I have an app running on parse.com backend, with users that creates profiles.

The format is jpeg and the resolution is 640X640.
I've noticed that some photos weights 150KB and other can reach to 500KB.
I want to optimize and reduce the images size without hurting image quality as much via image compression.

I've looked at
https://parse.com/docs/cloudcode/guide#cloud-code-modules

And it seems that the Image module only have crop and resize features. no compression.

How can i reduce the size of the stored jpeg without changing the reference from the object?

Sure i will need a background job... I just need help in figuring how to do it, and any things i need to worry about as the app is live with growing amount of users.

Thanks!

Comment: What is your client ? iOS, Android or web ?? Why do you want to compress things on the server when you can optimize the size on the client before upload ?

Comment: We're planning to compress it on the client side on the next version. But we still have thousands of photos there were already uploaded.

Comment: You cannot access the files on Parse storage directly, so you cannot resize or delete them. The files that are not linked to any record on your database remain in Parse storage unless you request Parse to clear them up for you. A solution might be to write a script to download those photos locally, compress them individually and re-upload them again replacing the old files on the server. Then request Parse to clean-up your storage to save some space.